# Testing query for SQL injection

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-injection

I have written a code in php which enables an admin to login. The password info is fetched from the table. I know it is not a good practice to write such kind of code and i should use prepared statement or mysqli_ but i just want to learn about sql query vulnerability. I just want to know how my code is vulnerable to SQL injection ? How can i bypass the password restriction. I tried inputting password = 'anything' OR 'x'='x' in the password field but it is not bypassing it.  This is my code:-

```
if(isset($_POST["Submit"]))
{
include 'db_connect.php';   
$user=$_POST['user'];
$pass=$_POST['pass'];
$checkquery="select * from adminlogin where password='$pass' ";
$queryex= mysql_query($checkquery);
$row= mysql_fetch_array($queryex);
$checkcasepass = $row['password'];
if($user=='admin' && strcmp($checkcasepass,$pass)==0)
{
setcookie("admin",$user);
setcookie ("student", "", time() - 3600);
header("location: admin option.php");
}
else
{
echo  "Sorry User Name and Password is Wrong";
}
}
```

---

I changed my query string to this for testing purpose:-

```
$checkquery="select * from adminlogin where password='$pass' OR 1=1 ";
```

but it didn't work. Can it be due to magic quotes ? But I am using PHP 5.4.3 and magic quotes is already depreciated. I am wondering why SQL injection is not working. ?

Comment: You should use `PDO` if you can help it, `mysql_*` functions are officially deprecated. Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). Check out [this comparison](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) and if you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: @dirt Whilst you are very correct to state this, the user specifically says they understand that and want to understand how injection works

Comment: why don't you just **echo** the resulting query and post it here?

Comment: why am i downvoted ???  I just want to understand how sql injection works. I always use PDO's in my project.

Comment: Here's an explanation: http://bobby-tables.com/about.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you choose to test for injection is wrong.

This code allows an injection all right, but verification code does check not number of rows found but returned value.

But again, speaking of SQL injection - it is fine with this code, injected all right.

Comment: Yup! I got it when i carefully examined the code. It is injecting but the code matches the value of the string with the column value that is fetched in the query.

Answer (score 1):

Change `'anything' OR 'x'='x'` to `anything' OR 'x'='x` The leading ' and trailing ' are already there, in effect the query you are trying will look like

```
select * from adminlogin where password=''anything' OR 'x'='x''
```

which isn't valid SQL

Comment: Getting this using var_dump :-  string 'select * from adminlogin where password='anything' OR 'x'='x' ' (length=62)

Comment: Getting this:- string 'select * from adminlogin where password='anything' OR 1=1' ' (length=59)

Comment: You have to comment out the rest of the string, like I pointed out in my example. You must do anything' OR 'x'='x';--

Comment: @Jonast92 no need to comment on for 'x' = 'x as select * from adminlogin where password='anything' OR 'x'='x' from the var_dump is valid SQL

Comment: If he wants to ignore the password part then he must. But my bad, he's only checking with 1 input instead of 2. (only checking for password, not useername aswell).

Comment: I tried changing it to 1=1 but again same result. string 'select * from adminlogin where password='anything' OR 1=1' ' (length=59)

Comment: @Vivek are you forgetting to ignore the last ' ?

Comment: I am entering anything' OR 1=1

Comment: Not sure if it will change anything but try where password='$pass';"; with the semicolon. BUT then again the examples that we are talking about may not work, read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16327878/is-this-php-code-vulnerable-to-any-sql-injection/16328084#comment23384290_16328084 and see what ppl were commenting about not working but something else that was working.

Comment: Even this is not working. I am getting this using var_dump:- string 'select * from adminlogin where password='somevalue' OR 1=1 ' (length=59) . This should work, but wondering why it isin't working.